# Generic mobile app to launch a browser with URL

Tags: cordova

Can I develop an app just to launch browser with a URL  ?
I'm planning to develop app using Phone Gap to support IOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.
Please guide me in giving valuable suggestion. This is my first day in Mobile Project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write an iOS app that opens a browser with a specific URL, but that's pretty much what PhoneGap does, but without the browser chrome (toolbars / URL bar)
So... I think Phonegap is what you need :)